# Incorrect URL in passing value from Html.AtionLink to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My **Controller**:-ForumController

**Action**:Topic

ViewPage to pass parameter is

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Topic", "Topic", "Forum", new { userid = "1" }, null)%>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Topic(String userid)
    {
        var topics = new topic { userId = userid };
        return View(topics);

    }
```

The parameter is getting passed but instead of getting URL **Forum/Topic/1**,I am getting **Forum/Topic?userid=1;**
Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you used the default route in `Global.asax` in which you have `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

So you should use the same name (`id`):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Topic", "Topic", "Forum", new { id = "1" }, null)%>
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Topic(String id)
{
    var topics = new topic { userId = id };
    return View(topics);
}
```

If you don't want to use `{id}` but some other token make sure you adjust your routes accordingly.

Comment: what could be done if i want it to change it to userId,because I am using userId everwhere

Comment: chenge your route definition in global.asax: `{controller}/{action}/{userid}`.

Comment: yes its working,but what is default route can u explain..can we create new routes

Comment: @prerna, the default route is what Visual Studio generates for you in Global.asax when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. You could certainly change it and add custom routes.